# PostgreSQL partition pruning

Tags: postgresql, performance, query-optimization, partitioning

The below query is intended to update records in an ID range: (Postgres14.4)

`UPDATE schema.table SET archived = TRUE WHERE id IN :ids`

Since it has to be executed in one transaction and the range consists roughly 1.5M records, I wanted to optimize it a bit. The table is partitioned by inserttime (range partitioning), so I figured I fetch the ids with a SUBQUERY and then execute the UPDATE using min and max inserttimes, so it will scan the related partitions only:

```
WITH subquery AS (
    SELECT table.id, table.insertTime
    FROM schema.table
    WHERE table.id IN :ids
),
min_max_times AS (
    SELECT MIN(insertTime) AS min_insert_time,
           MAX(insertTime) AS max_insert_time
    FROM subquery
)
UPDATE schema.table
SET archived = TRUE
FROM min_max_times, subquery
WHERE table.id = subquery.id
AND table.insertTime >= min_max_times.min_insert_time
AND table.insertTime <= min_max_times.max_insert_time;
```

With this approach the query runs through all partitions not once, but two times, both in  the SUBQUERY and on updating.

1. question:
   How can I enforce the planner to prune partitions and execute the UPDATE more efficiently? Putting the partition key into the WHERE clause usually helps.
2. question:
   Does this whole actually makes sense? My initial thought was that UPDATE is a more expensive operation than SELECT, so collecting the ids first and then updating their records is a smaller cost. But I'm starting to think that it is much better to just leave the UPDATE do its job while scanning through all (1st approach), like the SELECT does in the second approach anyways.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, the query has to scan all partitions, right? I agree that the first CTE looks pointless.

Comment: Yup, I probably overthinked it.